# Ionic 3 problemas para rodar projeto [Uncaught(in promise): cordova_not_available]

Tags: ionic, ionic3, npm

O projeto não foi criado por mim.

Não estou conseguindo rodar o projeto. Ao tentar rodar o projeto com o comando `ionic server` retorna a mensagem `Uncaught(in promise): cordova_not_available`.

Tentei remover a pasta `nome_modules` e rodar o comando `npm install`, mas gera o seguinte erro:

[image: Erro retornado]

Se eu entendi direito a mensagem de erro, fala que está faltando o `.NET Framework 2.0 SDK`. Mas eu já até reinstalei e continua retornando a mesma mensagem de erro.

A parte dois da mensagem, pelo que entendi, fala que tenho que instalar o `Microsoft Visual Studio`. Mas não faz o menor sentido to trabalhando com `Ionic` tem dois meses e nunca precisei disso. Inclusive fiz o procedimento de remover a pasta `node_modules` e rodar `npm install` em um `Mac` e não tive problema nenhum. O problema está dando no `Windows 8.1`.

Eu segui um tutorial que fala pra usar os comandos `ionic cordova platform add browser` e em seguida `ionic cordova run browser`. Ok... o projeto roda, mas vários componentes do layout não carregam.

Já não sei mais o que fazer pra rodar esse projeto corretamente.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui achar. Tem que instalar umas ferramentas de trabalho pro ambiente do `Windows`.

**Comando:**

```
npm install -g --production windows-build-tools
```